# How to replicate openssl encrypt/decrypt between PHP and Command Line?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-openssl

I am trying to create a PHP method to replicate the OpenSSL command line function so I can encrypt using the command line and then decrypt it using PHP or the opposite by encrypting using PHP and then decrypting using the command line.

the command line that is needed and this is fixed, I can not change it. I need to replicate it in PHP

```
openssl  enc -aes-256-cbc -in original.txt -out encrypted.bin -pass file:unwrappedoaep.key
```

I tried the below in PHP to replicate the above command line but it is not working.

```
$key = file_get_contents('unwrappedoaep.key');
$key = bin2hex($key);
$iv = '';

$data = file_get_contents('original.txt');
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

the above generated `$encrypted` string needs to be decrypted using the below command line, but it failed and got `bad magic number` , I need to modify the above PHP code to be able to generate an encrypted file similar to the one created using the command line to be able to decrypt it using the below command as it is exactly

```
openssl  enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in encrypted.bin -out decrypted.txt -pass file:unwrappedoaep.key
```

---

I try to decrypt a file encrypted by the command line, I use below PHP code as mentioned by @Topaco:

```
$salt = substr($encrypted, 8, 8);   //ignore first 8 'Salted__'
$ciphertext = substr($encrypted, 16);
$keyIv = EVP_BytesToKey($salt, $secret);
$key = substr($keyIv, 0, 32);
$iv = substr($keyIv, 32);

$original = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

where the function EVP_BytesToKey is defined:

```
function EVP_BytesToKey($salt, $password) {
    $bytes = '';
    $last = '';
    while(strlen($bytes) < 48) {
        $last = hash('sha256', $last . $password . $salt, true);
        $bytes.= $last;
    }
    return $bytes;
}
```

it is working if I create a file with a text inside it and in the command line use `-pass file:unwrappedoaep.key` and in the PHP replace the `$secret` with `file_get_contents('unwrappedoaep.key')`

but when i but in the `unwrappedoaep.key` a binary not a text then the decrypt from php method is not working anymore.

Comment: This can't work because OpenSSL *enc* uses a key derivation function (KDF) when using a password (the `-pass` option), which you didn't implement on the PHP side (`EVP_BytesToKey()`). Also, since you did not explicitly specify in the OpenSSL statement the digest that the KDF applies, the default digest is used. This depends on the OpenSSL version that you did not specify (what you still should do).

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71198954/9014097

Comment: i check the question, i can replicate it but when i change the password from `sw8/M!CLl:=cmgtHts?v/Wb7C$Vk9Sy-{go.*+E;[GAg~KQi*rI!1#z;x/KT` to any other password even if i change just one character i am not able to decrypt it again, is there special method to generate the password or i can set any password?
Thanks @Topaco

Comment: also when i try this command `openssl  enc -aes-256-cbc -in oringal.txt -out encrypted.bin -pass file:unwrappedoaep.key` on OpenSSL 3.0.9 it generate a file different from the one generate on other machine with OpenSSL 3.0.1 with same command line and can not decrypt it in the other machine also.

Comment: You can use *any* password. Of course, the password used for decryption must be the *same* as the one used for encryption. For the exact rules, see [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl.html), sec. *OPTIONS, Pass Phrase Options*. In case of continuing problems edit your question and post non-productive sample data (short plaintext, password, ciphertext (the latter e.g. Base64 encoded)), final used OpenSSL statement and PHP code.

Comment: Regarding *...generate a file different...*: Even using the *same* OpenSSL version, a different ciphertext is generated each time, because OpenSSL applies a (different) *random* salt each time when deriving the key during encryption. This is quite normal, the decryption still works because the salt is contained in the returned data.

Comment: Problems can arise when different digests are used: Quote from the linked post: *...In earlier versions OpenSSL used MD5 as digest in `EVP_BytesToKey()` by default, from version v1.1.0 SHA256...* So if you use v3.0.1, the default digest is SHA256 and you have to use SHA256 in `EVP_BytesToKey()` in the PHP code too and not MD5 (alternatively the digest can be set with *-md* in the OpenSSL command). If problems persist, edit the question and post code, statement and sample data that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: thanks @Topaco, i updated the question and mentioned your answer, yes when updating `EVP_BytesToKey()` to sha256 it is working, but still an issue just when the password is a file and the file contains binary not text.

Comment: Have you read the linked OpenSSL documentation? *...file:pathname: The first line of pathname is the password...*. Some KDF implementations (like probably OpenSSL) are designed for text data, so you should use text! Binary data (in the sense of byte sequences with values between 0x00 and 0xFF) might contain line breaks, so that the implementation only considers a part of the data. For special characters you might have to consider the [encoding](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man7/passphrase-encoding.html) additionally.

Comment: i tried to use `file('my.key')[0]` for the secret to get the first line as openssl command did in case if there is line break, but also decrypt still failed.

Comment: Ultimately, it depends on how your password is converted into a byte sequence (which is used as input to the KDF). Beside line breaks also the encoding plays a role (which must be identical on both sides). I have already explained all this. As said several times, post non-productive test data, that way it's just guesswork.

Comment: sure, this is an example of the key `EfUCsPZz2b9NxTWKGIR2Bw==` I used, sure i just base64 encode it `base64_encode((file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/my.key')))` and i encrypt using the command line `>openssl  enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in my-encrypted.bin -pass file:my.key -P`  

and below is the command line result:  

    salt=FA5B7B31B079E108  
    key=16D88F1893B5C53AC3A65D4F7889DF07F40EA96BD6BCF5AB81256BAC591D683D  
    iv =24DFFFC16FEA18199EC6EACF18A05DBD

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense like this: 1. don't post the data in a comment, but edit your question and post the additional data at the end (e.g. with an introductory edit). 2. post a consistent and complete description of your test case: you say *...i encrypt...*, but post a command to decrypt *...-d ... -in my-encrypted.bin...*. And how was *my-encrypted.bin* created and what is actually the *problem* etc. etc.

Comment: By the way, I can't see any problem here either, because I can reproduce key and IV with the PHP/`EVP_BytesToKey()` implementation you posted, see https://paiza.io/projects/x55EMh2tA-gHbWpHhgA90g. So what is actually the problem here?

Comment: Decrypting a ciphertext generated with OpenSSL using the PHP code also works, s. https://paiza.io/projects/m0tEfX-d0fRdAl5Lta4gvg.

Comment: sorry for that @Topaco, I just generate another key as sample data which is valid i regenerated another key that I think not able to decrypt, i updated the code with the needed data [https://paiza.io/projects/mq9Jo7syLdhsUq4faoj6Yg](https://paiza.io/projects/mq9Jo7syLdhsUq4faoj6Yg)

Comment: note that i debug the key and try build key character by character so first try key as first character only, then test key as first and second characters only and continue till test the whole full key length.

i find that the first 5 characters work so here as base64 it is: 'AZ50guQ='

but how can i get this key portion directly without loop and test decrypt each time? how to get the first line as considered by openssl.

Comment: I already explained this! OpenSSL assumes text data. Binary data can contain line breaks. This is the case in your example. If you hex encode the key (instead of Base64) it is 019e7482e40a21284cb4... Already the sixth byte is 0x0a (LF, Line Feed), which (OS dependent) is interpreted as line break ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552775/9014097)). Thus, OpenSSL uses as password only 019e7482e4 or Base64 encoded (instead of hex) AZ50guQ=.

Comment: If you use *arbitrary* binary data, this is *not* reliable! Depending on the OS, specific byte sequences may result in a failure (and 0x0a is just *one* example). You can put in any workarounds, but that may not be robust and additionally reduces performance. If you can't change the OpenSSL statement (in the sense that you apply keys *directly*, i.e. without PBKDF), you have to accept the limitations of the OpenSSL implementation and use text data.

Comment: thanks @Topaco it is clear now, if you can paste the first 2 comments about EVP_BytesToKey as answer to check it as the accepted answer

Comment: The comments refer to the lack of the key derivation function in the PHP code, which is already the subject of various posts e.g. [Openssl aes-256-cbc encryption from command prompt and decryption in PHP (and vice versa)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71198954/9014097). Therefore, this post here should actually be closed as a duplicate. So, to avoid redundancy, I'm not going to post an answer, but thanks for the offer.